# URL decoding/encoding NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using three20's URL navigator and I want to create a map as follows:

```
[map from:[Group class] name:@"show" toURL:@"tt://group/(gid)/(name)"];
```

The issue here name can be multiple words and so there is spaces in between.
Now I need to URL encode this `NSString` and decode it back. How do I do this?
What is the easiest way to URL decode and encode `NSString`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c iPhone percent encode a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)encodedURLString {
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)self,
                                                                           NULL,                   
                                                                           CFSTR("?=&+"),          
                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8); // encoding
    return [result autorelease];
}

- (NSString *)encodedURLParameterString {
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                           (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           CFSTR(":/=,!$&'()*+;[]@#?"),
                                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

to get the url from the NSString.

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590545/urlencoding-a-string-with-objective-c) about URLencoding it with the proper escapes.

Comment: I don't want an URL, I want a NSString which is string encoded