# ios UTF8 encoding from nsstring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am receiving a nsstring that is not properly encoded like "mystring%201, where must be "mystring 1". How could I replace all characters that could be interpreted as UTF8? I read a lot of posts but not a full solution. Please note that nsstring is already encoded wrong and I am not asking about how to encode char sequence. Thank you.

Comment: are you asking about URI encoding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` is what you want. basically use it like so:

```
newString = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Strings and Non-ASCII Characters` section of [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html):

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Long \xe2\x80\x94   dash"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lblDate.text=[NSString stringWithCString:[[arrTripDetail valueForKey:Param_vCurrencySymbol] UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**U can Convert & get Custom Emoji to string**

eg :

> input : \U20b9
>
> Output: ₹

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 1):

Do you want just percent encoding/decoding or full URL encoding/decoding? -(NSString*)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: will work if it is just percent encoding, but if there is full URL encoding there (so, for example a space could be either %20 or +) then you'll need something like the url decoding in the three20 library (or search on there, there are lots of examples of how to do it such as [URL decoding/encoding NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688287/url-decoding-encoding-nsstring)).