# android UTF8 encoding from received string

Tags: java, android

I am receiving a string that is not properly encoded like `mystring%201`, where must be `mystring 1`. How could I replace all characters that could be interpreted as UTF8? I read a lot of posts but not a full solution. Please note that string is already encoded wrong and I am not asking about how to encode char sequence. I asked same issue for iOS few days ago and was solved using `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Thank you.

[ios UTF8 encoding from nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786075/ios-utf8-encoding-from-nsstring)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [URLDecoder.decode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html) function, like this:

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your string is partially URL-encoded, so...
how about this:

```
try {
 System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("mystring%201", "UTF-8"));
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so how can use output?

Answer (score 4):

> I am receiving a string that is not properly encoded like
> "mystring%201

Well this string is already `encoded`, you have to decode:

```
String sDecoded = URLDecoder.decode("mystring%201", "UTF-8");
```

so now `sDecoded` must have the value of "`mystring 1`".

#### The "Encoding" of String:

```
String sEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("mystring 1", "UTF-8");
```

`sEncoded` must have the value of "`mystring%201`"