# Special charaters show square box in webservice response

Tags: android, parsing, dictionary, textview, special-characters

Here is the word pronounciation coming in my web services response **tækˈsɑ:nəmi**
but when i show it android textview it shows like this **tÃ¦kËsÉ:nÉmi** And also sometime it shows Square boxes in place of some characters when i show it in android textview.

Please guide or suggest some solution.

Ali

Comment: Probably your server isn't sending Unicode UTF8 encoded strings (i.e.: a Windows based server left with the default encoding).

Comment: So the correction should be on server side ?

Comment: Basically I am fetching date from an API server over which I don't have control to change encoding format.Can you suggest something i can do on client side?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040765/android-utf8-encoding-from-received-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to solve this after consulting with a genius guy.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form- urlencoded");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Here is the magical line of code.

```
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Cheers. Ali