# XCode iOS replace spaces with +

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsurl

Need help to replace my spaces from the textfield entry for posting to a GET

My current code:

```
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", messageBox.text];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

[messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:add]];
```

However I tried

```
NSString *finalAdd = [add stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL decoding/encoding NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688287/url-decoding-encoding-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the parameter

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", [messageBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: Gives me: No visible @interface for 'NSURL' declares the selector 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:'

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187316/string-wont-url-encode-in-ios). Both offer good solutions for encoding urls.

Comment: Please only url or link answers are note truly good and will be rejected by community soon :)