# Correct URL encoding in Cocoa (ObjC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, urlencode

I am trying to URL encode an NSString but I can't seem to find the proper way (I'm new to Obj C). I have been searching around but can't find a decent answer. So:

What is the correct, and modern, way to encode an NSString like a URL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL encode a NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688287/url-decoding-encoding-nsstring, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187316/string-wont-url-encode-in-ios

Comment: [NSString URLEncoding](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding to UTF-8:

```
NSString *strUTF8 = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Wrong answer. Translates "This is my + statement. Got it?" to "This%20is%20my%20+%20statement.%20Got%20it?" instead of "This+is+my+%2B+statement.+Got+it%3F". Note it doesn't properly encoded the plus and the question mark characters.